# How do I write a Junit test for a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, junit, threadpoolexecutor

How can I write a Junit test for the following function. ParallelExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor and the WorkerThread will call latch.countDown() on a value change(listener). WorkerThread is a 3 party class. Please let me know how I can tell the test to decrease the latch.

```
    public static void OpenScreen() throws InterruptedException {
//some job...3 party screen
    // creating the ThreadPoolExecutor
    final ParallelExecutor executorPool = new ParallelExecutor(10);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(0);
    // start the monitoring thread
    final MyMonitorThread monitor = new MyMonitorThread(executorPool, 3);
    final Thread monitorThread = new Thread(monitor);
    monitorThread.start();
    // monitorThread.start();
    // submit work to the thread pool
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executorPool.execute(new WorkerThread(("cmd" + i), latch));
    }

    latch.await();
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    // shut down the pool
    executorPool.shutdownNow();
    // shut down the monitor thread
    monitor.shutdown();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what do you want to test? :-) That the execute methods are called? The counting works? Timeouting works if one of the tasks take too much to execute? All the jobs completed when the `openScreen()` method returns?

If you want to do unit tests, you can play around with mocks (for that, I'd extract this functionality to a separate class where the dependencies like the pool and monitor are passed/injected for the new class). There you can verify if the methods were called properly.